# Javascript - value of textarea not formatted when put in <p>

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to take the content from a textarea and put it in a `<p>`, and then print that, so I can print the whole textarea. However, when I take the value of the textarea and put it in the `<p>` it looses all formatting, as in everything looks like a minified JS file. Does anyone know how to keep the formatting when copying to a `<p>` tag?

My code:

```
document.getElementById('bigthing').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('printtext').style.display = 'block';
document.getElementById('printtext').innerHTML = document.getElementById('output').value;
window.print();
document.getElementById('printtext').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('bigthing').style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: Could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: @RahilWazir http://jsfiddle.net/7LvCZ/ except the `print()` function doesn't seem to work in JsFiddle, but it does if you run in ur browser

Comment: Heres the updated http://jsfiddle.net/7LvCZ/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because in textarea, content is a string. line breaks are like "\n". Not as 
.
When you assign it directly to "innerHTML" of paragraph element (p), those "\n" are ignored because "\" is escape character. you will see the rest of plain text.

```
document.getElementById('txtareafieldId').value //let value is aa in two lines => a\na\n
document.getElementById('paraId').innerHTML // it will display as "a a"
```

Note that space between a and a. Its because of ignored "\n".

Regex to replace line breaks:

```
var val =  document.getElementById('txtareafieldId').value;
var fval = val.replace(/\n/g,"<br/>");
document.getElementById('paraId').innerHTML =fval;
```

Comment: so the only way to do this is to analyse line by line, replacing '\n' with `<br>`?

Comment: OR i could sneak in `<br>` at the end of every line in the textarea! but that would be sneaky... and lazy...

Comment: or increase the height of the textarea to fit its contents before printing.

Comment: Use regex to replace them. added that code snippet in answer. check it out.

Comment: I managed to just use `replace(/\n/gi, '<br>')`, which seems to work. Thanks for the help though

Comment: It isn't just line breaks you need to deal with. What if the textarea contains <tags>?

Comment: all those special characters need to parsed by regex. "\n", "\t", "<", ">"," " "(double quote) and " ' "(single quote). if i missed anything else pls add them in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of reading the content of your textarea, and placing into into a paragraph before printing, you could try to just increase the height of the textarea to include all of the content:

```
yourTextArea.style.height = yourTextArea.scrollHeight + "px";
```

Then you can change it back afterwards.

Comment: Yes, but this way the page i print can be very bare very easily.